How to put logarithmic equations in qucs
I need to put the equation shown in the below image in my QUCS simulation.
I directly entered that equation in equation editor but it is not working.Can you please help me.


I tried to put the second equation as shown below.But I am getting an error.

Made the changes suggested ,but still error is coming.

Still the error is coming.

I made all changes as per your latest post,but still getting an error.If you don't mind could you please check the below image.



You don't have to put in the equation exactly as shown. The tutorial below shows on page 42 how to setup a S-parameter simulation and the simplified equations needed for plotting the parameters in dB. https://qucs.github.io/docs/tutorial/getstarted.pdf

Thank you very much for the document.I edited the question with one more equation.May I know how to insert it

You need to set up an AC-Simulation instead of a S-Parameter simulation. If you look closely to the second screenshot you posted, it says "an AC frequency sweep is simulated". The equation for |S21| is fine for an AC sim.

I just realized you also want to do a parameter sweep. For that to happen, change R3 from "R=50 Ohm" to something like "R=RL" and the parameter sweep setup to "Param=RL".

I made the changes you suggested,but still error is coming.

Main problem is that you are still using a S-parameter simulation. Switch to AC-simulation. Looks like you are also missing the "" operator in the dBS21 = (2OUT.v/Vo.v) equation. QUCS will probably spit out an error message because of that.

Still error is coming plase see the latest image. Yes I need to do S parameter simulation as given in this document page 15(https://www.omicron-lab.com/fileadmin/assets/Bode_100/ApplicationNotes/Modelling_Wireless_Power_Transfer_Link/App_Note_Modelling_Wireless_Power_Transfer_Link_V2.pdf).

Page 15 is asking for an AC frequency sweep (AC simulation). The circuit is fed with a voltage source not power source(s) like in the examples on page 13,14,16. With the AC-simulation you can then plot |S21| as requested. I'll post a simple example for you made with Qucs(Studio). Of course you could calculate and plot S-paramaters form an AC-simulation but that is imo unnecessarily complicated as shown on page 43 in the Qucs tutorial I linked previously.

AC-simulation in Qucs(Studio) for a simple, arbitrary lowpass filter:


I recommend studying the Qucs(Studio) tutorials from Gunthard Kraus (DG8GB) which are also available in english:
http://www.gunthard-kraus.de/qucsstudio/index_english_qucsstudio.html

Thank for the support.I made all changes suggested by you,but still getting an error could you please check my latest update

Trying to plot "dBS21" is invalid because it doesn't exist anymore ;-) . According to the equations block, you renamed your S21 plot to "s21db". Double click on the scalar plot and replace the invalid label with the correct one.

Yes.l corrected .it's working now thank you.
